# String resource returns a number?

Tags: java, android, string, android-resources

In my android project I have a string resource (string.xml) in the res/ folder.

in that string.xml I have created several strings, like:

```
<string name="my_server">http://12.34.56.78</string>
<string name="my_port">1234</string>
```

then I use in the code:

```
String url = R.strings.my_server + ":" + R.strings.my_port;
System.out.println("My server and port is: " + url);
```

but my output is:

> My server and port is : 2131099700:2131099702

Where is my string? That seem kind a adress of that string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse/Java - Values in R.string.\* return int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983548/eclipse-java-values-in-r-string-return-int)

Answer (score 3):

Change :

```
<string name="my_server">http://12.34.56.78</string>
...

String url = R.strings.my_server + ":" + R.strings.my_port;
```

to

```
<string name="my_server">http:\/\/12.34.56.78</string>
...

String url = getString(R.strings.my_server) + ":" + getString(R.strings.my_port);
```

You needed to escape the `my_server` string, plus use the [getString(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) method to retrieve the `strings`.

Comment: Nope, when I just have the server without port : String url = R.strings.my_server; // Android studio complains: required String, found int. Offers to use String.valueOf()

Comment: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.example.json.JacksonRequest).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: I see that this error has something to do with the **Jackson** parser you are using, not this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the String value of a string resource like this for example:

```
String yourString = context.getResources().getString(R.string.my_port);
```

where `context` is the context of your activity

or like this if you import `import android.content.res.Resources`:

```
String yourString = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.my_port);
```

Comment: I get an android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: unknown resource 2131099700

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are actually refering to a Id in your R File not to the Value connected with it.

You need to do that in order to get the String:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.my_server)
```

According to the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) you don't need to escape '/'.

Answer (score 0):

R.string will return the `id` of that particular string in form of an `Integer`.

To get actual string, you will use `getResources().getString(R.string.your_string);`

So, your `url` string will be like this

```
String url = getResources().getString(R.strings.my_server) + ":" + getResources().getString(R.strings.my_port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that you need to use `context` and `getString` method:

```
context.getString(R.id.your_string_name)
```

For example in my adapter class, I defines the Context as

```
private Context mContext;
```

Then I use it in the message section of alert dialog as

```
...

.setMesasge(mContext.getString(R.string.my_string_name))

...
```