# How I resolve the String/int Error?

Tags: java, android, string, char

The code

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"text..text"));
```

works fine, but the code

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,R.string.listen));
```

Gives me the error "Wrong 2nd argument type. Found 'int', required 'java.lang.CharSequence'."

But my R.string.listen isn't a int, it is a string.

Comment: have you checked if the overrided method used is correct?

Comment: `R.string.listen` is an int not a String.

Comment: `R.string.listen` gives you the reference index of that string you will have to use `getString(R.string.listen)`

Comment: Simply add .toString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.string.listen` is an `int` not a `String`. All elements under R are ints (ids, strings, layouts, raws...). They are identifiers for the resources inside the APK, not the real resource itself.

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.listen)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,getString(R.string.listen)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything in the `R class` is a reference, hence it's just defined as an int.

Thus `R.string.*` is a reference to an int in R.java that points to your actual String.

Therefore in your case `R.string.listen` gives you the reference index of that string resource, you will need to call `getString()` method to get the value of that string.

You can use either `getString(int)` or `getText(int)` to retrieve a string.

```
getText(int) retains any rich text styling applied to the string
```

See the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String) and this similar [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1983548/3521116) for more information